# Unit testing methods which do not produce a distinct output

Tags: java, unit-testing, vaadin

In my Vaadin GUI application, there are so many methods which look like below.

```
@Override
protected void loadLayout() {
    CssLayout statusLayout = new CssLayout();

    statusLayout.addComponent(connectedTextLabel);
    statusLayout.addComponent(connectedCountLabel);
    statusLayout.addComponent(notConnectedTextLabel);
    statusLayout.addComponent(notConnectedCountLabel);

    connectionsTable.getCustomHeaderLayout().addComponent(statusLayout);
    connectionsTable.getCustomHeaderLayout().addComponent(commandLayout);
    connectionsTable.getCustomHeaderLayout().addComponent(historyViewCheckbox);

    bodySplitter.addComponent(connectionsTable);
    bodySplitter.addComponent(connectionHistoryTable);
    bodySplitter.setSplitPosition(75, Sizeable.Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    bodySplitter.setSizeFull();
    bodyLayout.addComponent(bodySplitter);

    if (connectionDef.getConnectionHistoryDef() == null) {
        historyViewCheckbox.setVisible(false);
    }
    if (connectionDef.getConnectionStatusField() == null || connectionDef.getConnectedStatusValue() == null || connectionDef.getConnectedStatusValue().isEmpty()) {
        connectedTextLabel.setVisible(false);
        connectedCountLabel.setVisible(false);
        notConnectedTextLabel.setVisible(false);
        notConnectedCountLabel.setVisible(false);
    }
}


protected void setStyleNamesAndControlIds() {
    mainLayout.setId("mainLayout");
    header.setId("header");
    footer.setId("footer");
    propertyEditorLayout.setId("propertyEditorLayout");
    propertyEditor.setId("propertyEditor");

    mainLayout.setStyleName("mainLayout");
    propertyEditorLayout.setStyleName("ui_action_edit");
    header.setStyleName("TopPane");
    footer.setStyleName("footer");
}
```

These methods are used for setting up the layout of GUIs. They do not produce a single distinct output. Almost every line in these methods is doing a separate job, which is not almost relevant to other lines.

Usually, when unit testing a method, I check the return value of the method, or validate calls on a limited number of external objects such as database connections.

But, for methods like above, there is no such single output. If I wrote unit tests for such methods, My test code checks for each method call happens in every line in the method, and in the end, it looks almost like the method itself.

If someone altered the code in any way, the test will break and they will have to update the test to match the change. But, there is no assurance that the change didn't actually break anything since test doesn't check the actual UI drawn in the browser.

For an example, if someone changed a style name of a control, he will have to update the test code with the new style name and the test will pass. But, for things to actually work without any issue, he has to change the relevant scss style files too. But the test didn't make any contribution to detect this issue. Same applies to layout setup code as well.

Is there any advantage of writing unit tests like above, other than keeping the code coverage rating at a higher level? For me, it feels useless and writing a test to compare the decompiled bytecode of the method to the original decompiled bytecode kept as a string in the test looks much better than these kinds of tests.

Comment: Isn't there a way to compile the app to html/javascript? If so, then you can do this and test that generated output...somehow. I'm not familiar with vaadin

Comment: IMHO you couldn't write a good test in such method since it doesn't follow the SRP principle. I would suggest you to change your test approach to a framework that do automated tests in the actual front end such as  Selenium or TestingWhiz or some other alike

Comment: Here is a list of some https://dzone.com/articles/top-10-automated-software-testing-tools

Comment: Just searching and I found this question: https://vaadin.com/forum/message/512218. You may have to redesign here, but I think this is basically what it should be. Each component should be testable, so you just have to identify the components to test and spin up a simple junit test class for each one you want

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any advantage of writing unit tests like above, other than
>   keeping the code coverage rating at a higher level?

Yes, if you take a sensible approach.  It might not make sense, as you say, to test that a control has a particular style.  So focus your tests on the parts of your code that are likely to break.  If there is any conditional logic that goes into producing your UI, test that logic.  The test will then protect your code from future changes that could break your logic.

As for you comment about testing methods that don't return a value, you can address that several ways.

1. It's your code, so you can restructure it to be more testable.  Think about breaking it down into smaller methods.  Isolate your logic into individual methods that can be called in a test.
2. Indirect verification - Rather than focusing on return values, focus on the effect your method has on other objects in the system.

Finally consider if unit testing of the UI is right for you and your organization.  UIs are often difficult to unit test (as you have pointed out).  Many companies write functional tests for their UIs.  These are tests that drive the UI of the actual product.  This is very different from unit tests which do not require the full product and are targeted at very small units of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one simple example you could look to see how to fly over your application and try what is needed. This is vaadin 8, CDI & Wildfly Swarm example and in no way the only way to test UI's of Vaadin application.

https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-examples/blob/master/vaadin/src/it/java/org/wildfly/swarm/it/vaadin/VaadinApplicationIT.java